# Laravel 5 write visited urls and used browser to txt file

Tags: logging, laravel-5

I'm new to laravel and I have made my first web page with it and I would also like to create a text file in which I'll write visited urls and what browser was used to access it. Will you please help me?

Comment: Anything in particular that you've tried so far?

Comment: well i'm still new to laravel so i don't know where to start, i've been looking for some tutorials online and only thing i could find was how to make a log file but nothing about writing visited urls and browsers to a file